# OpenGL Changing the thickness of rendered faces

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, clipping

I am trying to create a cross-section of a model. The system works fine, but when the model is clipped, it appears invisible when you line the camera directly with it.

I was just wondering if there was a way change how thick faces rendered with GL_FILL so it is easier to see the edges of the cross-section.

The current effect is like when you no-clip in a video game and line up with a wall.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL primitives are always infinitely thin. And no, you can't make them "thick". That's how rasterizers work. If you want some kind of thickness, you must implement it yourself, by clipping the geometry and "solidifying" it yourself.

I don't know a good reference to look at. But if you feel adventurous you may want to take a look at the source code of Blender's "Solidify" mesh modifier.